# What is Object Oriented Scanner (Lexical Analysis)?

Tags: lexical-analysis, compiler-construction, compiler-development

Recently I came across the concept of Lexical Analysis called "Object Oriented Scanner", but I wasn't able to distinguish it from the normal scanning technique. What can be the extra things in object oriented scanner, please help me understanding this concept... what can be object orientation in terms of Lexical analysis?

Comment: Do you have a reference, by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.inf.uos.de/alumni/bernd/oolex/staff/paper_oolex.pdf) should interest you, it is the theory behind [oolex](http://www.inf.uos.de/alumni/bernd/oolex/).

You should also look into the theory behind object oriented scanners, as in the proceedings of CompSysTech 2000:  **CompSysTech '00 Proceedings of the conference on Computer systems and technologies**, where "From structure oriented to object oriented scanner design" was published. You will need a membership from the ACM if you can't find it in your university's library, but you can check [this](http://luna2.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/alumni/bernd/lolo/staff/paper_lolo.pdf) and [this](http://www.jroller.com/thinksInCode/category/Intercalc) in the meantime. The last link is some Java with appropriate explanations.

Comment: That seems like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Hi Kheldar, thanks for the link.. I have read the documentation for the oolex but it didn't satisfied me, they have shown what they have done with the scanner, how its working. but it doesn't specify what should you expect with object oriented scanner, how it should scan the characters and make the tokens from them. what can be done different from a regular scanner.

Comment: The purpose of SO is to write answers that give explanations to a question in a way in which the answer resides on SO. Offsite links are potentially useful, but do not explain anything; they are commentary, and when that is all that is provided, they are a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: Given the complexity of the theory, I don't think it's explainable on SO. On the other hand, if I was intelligent to be a Professor, i'd be one :D